# Word to describe ideological based giving? (outside of tithing, more specific than charitable)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes "a group of people that give to others that

1. Share similar beliefs
2. Promote a related cause
3. Serve as a good example of what the group believes in"

Consider that religious groups will support musicians that associate themselves to the same religion, or vote for a particular candidate.

I'm trying to find a word that describes (or is even related to) the shared economic support based on a communities values, or consensus.

The reason I'm looking for this word is because I found a marginalized group of people who are not organized economically, and being a non-religious non-hierarchical society, they don't have such a "system" benefiting them.  Therefore this "social movement" or its potential, is at a standstill.

I'm looking for a word to explain what it is they are missing, and the socio-economic feature present in religious groups.

Comment: "Humans" .Everybody does that sometimes. Most people tend to carry this practice all the way to even saying "hello" only to friends and family.

Answer (score 1):

***[Contribute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/contribute)*** or ***Contribution*** is a good word to describe this activity, suggesting an ***investment*** that ***unifies*** the ***group*** around a common purpose. The prefix *con* for *together*, implies the unifying principle.

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1. Give (something, especially money) in order to help achieve or provide something:

Etymology [***contribute***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=contribute&searchmode=none)

> 1520s,
>
> from Latin contributus, past participle of contribuere "to bring
>   together, add, unite, collect, contribute" (see contribution).
>
> Figurative sense is from 1630s.
>
> Related: Contributed; contributing.

[***contribution***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=contribution&allowed_in_frame=0)

> late 14c.,
>
> from Old French contribution and directly from Latin contributionem
>   (nominative contributio), noun of action from past participle stem of
>   contribuere "to bring together, add, contribute,"
>
> from com- "together" (see com-) + tribuere "to allot, pay" (see
>   tribute).

***[tribute](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tribute&allowed_in_frame=0)***

> mid-14c.,
>
> "stated sum of money or other valuable consideration paid by one ruler
>   or country to another in acknowledgment of submission or as the price
>   of peace or protection,"
>
> from Anglo-French tribute, Old French tribut and directly
>
> from Latin tributum "tribute, a stated payment, a thing contributed or
>   paid," noun use of neuter of tributus, past participle of tribuere "to
>   pay, assign, grant," also "allot among the tribes or to a tribe,"
>
> from tribus (see tribe). Sense of "offering, gift, token" is first
>   recorded 1580s.

***[tribe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tribe&allowed_in_frame=0)***

> mid-13c.,
>
> "one of the twelve divisions of the ancient Hebrews," from Old French
>   tribu
>
> or directly from Latin tribus "one of the three political/ethnic
>   divisions of the original Roman state" (Tites, Ramnes, and Luceres,
>   corresponding, perhaps, to the Latins, Sabines, and Etruscans), later,
>   one of the 30 political divisions instituted by Servius Tullius
>   (increased to 35 in 241 B.C.E.), of unknown origin.
>
> Perhaps from tri- "three" + *bheue-, root of the verb be.
>
> Others connect the word with the PIE root *treb- "a dwelling" (see
>   tavern).

It is not necessary for the unifying principle of a group to be religious.

Comment: In our church we call it a Fast Offering. It is administered by the Bishop to members in need. However, My understanding is that surplus Fast Offerings are distributed to non-members as well, such as victims of natural disasters.

Answer (score 1):

To describe the group:

***[Affiliation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/affiliate)*** and ***[Fraternity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fraternity)*** imply a close familiar connection

***[Affiliate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/affiliate)***

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT] (usually be affiliated with)
>   1. Officially attach or connect (a subsidiary group or a person) to an organization:
>
> 1.1 [NO OBJECT] Officially join or become attached to an organization:
>
> NOUN
>
> A person or organization officially attached to a larger body:
>
> **Origin**
>
> mid 18th century: from medieval Latin affiliat- 'adopted as a son',
>
> from the verb affiliare, from ad- 'toward' + filius 'son'.

***[Fraternity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fraternity)***

> NOUN (plural fraternities)
>
> 1 [TREATED AS SINGULAR OR PLURAL] A group of people sharing a common
>   profession or interests:
>
> **Origin**
>
> Middle English: from Old French fraternite,
>
> from Latin fraternitas,
>
> from fraternus (see fraternal).
>
> ***fraternal***:
>
> late Middle English:
>
> from medieval Latin fraternalis,
>
> from Latin fraternus,
>
> from frater 'brother'.

---

***[Coalition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/coalition)*** or ***[Partnership](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/partnership)*** imply a slightly looser connection

***[Coalition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/coalition)***

> NOUN
>
> An alliance for combined action, especially a temporary alliance of
>   political parties forming a government or of states:
>
> [AS MODIFIER]: a coalition government
>
> **Origin**
>
> early 17th century (in the sense 'fusion'):
>
> from medieval Latin coalitio(n-),
>
> from the verb coalescere (see coalesce).
>
> Usage in politics dates from the late 18th century.

***[Coalesce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/coalesce)***

> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Come together and form one mass or whole:
>
> 1.1 [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Combine (elements) in a mass or whole:
>
> **Origin**
>
> mid 16th century (in the sense 'bring together, unite'):
>
> from Latin coalescere,
>
> from co- (from cum 'with') + alescere 'grow up' (from alere
>   'nourish').

---

***[Alliance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/alliance)*** or ***[Confederation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/confederation)*** imply an agreement among groups that maintain unique identity.